# Restarting a COUNTIF function depending on multiple criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, countif

I have a sheet with 4 columns, as shown below:

| 1 | Date | Item Name | Counter | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Date 1 | Item A | 1 |  |
| 4 | Date 1 | Item B | 1 |  |
| 5 | Date 2 | Item B | 2 |  |
| 6 | Date 3 | Item A | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | Date 3 | Item B | 3 |  |
| 8 | Date 4 | Item A | 1 |  |
| 9 | Date 5 | Item A | 2 |  |

Currently, I'm using a countif function [=countif(B$2:B2,B2)] to count the number of times a specific item appears in the spreadsheet. However, I need to find a way to restart the counter if there is a 1 in column D. In this case, this would mean that the formula in row 8 column C would be [=COUNTIF(B$8:B8,B8)] and would continue counting until it finds another row with a 1 in column D (e.g., formula in column C row 9 would be =COUNTIF(B$8:B9,B9). It would also ideally check whether there is a prior row with a 1 in column D, not through the order of the sheet, but by checking that it's date is smaller (and yet the closest date with a 1 in column D).

I've written the following script, which sets the row with a 1 in column D to 0 and sets the countif for the starting rows correctly to [=countif(B$2:B2,B2)], but it sets any row after there is a row with a 1 in column D as the same formula, with the starting range at B$2.

```
function setCountifFormula() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { //iterate through each row
    var colBValue = data[i][1]; //get columnB in i
    var colAValue = data[i][0]; // get date in i
    var colDValue = data[i][3]; // get flag in i
    var closestRow = 1; // empty variable
    
    if( colDValue == "1") { //if columnD = 1 
      sheet.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(0); // set columnC = 0
    } else {
      for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) { //iterate through other rows
        if (data[j][1] === colBValue && data[j][3] === "1") { // if columnB in j = ColumnB in i, and flag in row j = 1 
          var dateToCompare = data[j][0]; //set datetoCompare = date in row j
          closestRow = j;
          if (dateToCompare < colAValue) {
            var range = "B$" + (closestRow + 1) + ":B" + (i + 1);
            var formula = "=COUNTIF(" + range + ",B" + (i + 1) + ")";
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setFormula(formula);
          } else {
            var range = "B$2:B" + (i+1);
            var formula = "=COUNTIF(" + range + ",B" + (i+1) + ")";
            sheet.getRange(i+1, 3).setFormula(formula);
          }
        }
      }
      if (closestRow === 1) {
        var range = "B$2:B" +(i+1);
        var formula = "=COUNTIF("+range +",B"+(i+1)+")";
        sheet.getRange(i+1,3).setFormula(formula);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can post the spreadsheet if needs be. If there is a different way without using scripts or COUNTIF, it'd be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm much better at scripting than complex formulas so here is an example of how I would do it.

[image]

```
function myCountif() {
  try {
    let values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    values.shift(); // remove headers
    let unique = values.map( row => row[1] );
    unique = [...new Set(unique)];
    let count = unique.map( row => 0 );
    let counts = values.map( row => 0 );
    values.forEach( (row,rIndex) => {
        let cIndex = unique.findIndex( item => item === row[1] );
        count[cIndex] = count[cIndex]+1;
        counts[rIndex] = count[cIndex];
        if( row[3] === 1 ) count[cIndex] = 0;
      }
    )
    return counts;
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Array.shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Set Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)